# Double eyeshot toolbar icons

Tags: c#, winforms, eyeshot

The C# Winforms Eyeshot toolbar is too small.  Is there anyway to increase the size of the buttons.

I would not be opposed to overwriting the [toolbar draw method](http://documentation.devdept.com/110/winforms/topic1612.html), but I have no idea what I would do there to enlarge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing model.ButtonStyle.Size property